# install numpy to ironpython (using in c# code)

Tags: c#, python, numpy, scipy, ironpython

I use ironPython in my C# project via a nuget package.
now I want to use numpy functions in a *.py script and call that from my c# code via ironpython.
I allready tried to install numpy via cmd into ironpython but it don't worked to me.

Is there a way to help me out (maybe with a little tutorial about that)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't much experience with IronPython, but I believe it does not natively support third party libraries like numpy. I believe that Python.NET may be a better solution if this is what you require. (http://pythonnet.github.io/)